# double acctupdateinterval on queries.conf (section interim-update)

Tags: mysql, freeradius

We use Coova Chilli and Freeradius for wifi authentication.

Sometimes, we see on the nas that people stay connected even if we have an acctstoptime not null. If I look more closely, I can see the acctupdatetime continue is incremented without an acctterminatecause. (blank field)

After looking at the file mysql / queries.conf, I saw on interim-update this:

```
query = "\
                UPDATE ${....acct_table1} \
                SET \
                    acctupdatetime  = (@acctupdatetime_old:=acctupdatetime), \
                    acctupdatetime  = FROM_UNIXTIME(\
                        %{integer:Event-Timestamp}), \
                    acctinterval    = %{integer:Event-Timestamp} - \
                        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@acctupdatetime_old), \
```

You see the double acctupdatetime? Is that normal? I looked the others mods, and did't see this in double.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Acct-Session-ID reuse to me.  This identifier is meant to be unique to the NAS and unique in time, but many vendors don't respect this requirement. I've seen this sort of thing happen on Cisco WLCs, where the STA roams between APs.  The session will stop, and then be re-started without the Acct-Session-ID changing.

You could change the query to re-open the session, i.e. set acctstoptime to NULL if you receive an Interim, but that's about it I'm afraid.